# Javascript onclick event declation with if-else

Tags: javascript

I m newer to javascript, Now i am getting started to javascript.

Here is the link(run with example):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Here, i have raised one doubt,

```
  if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
//do stuff
}
```

May i know, what is "bulbon" why we have use?

And i tried another one example, Here is my code:

```
<img width="300px" height="300px" src="dim-bulb.jpg" id="bulb" onclick="changebulb()"  alt=bulb"/>
<script>
function changebulb() {

var image=document.getElementById("bulb");
if(image.src.match("bulbon")) {
image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
}
else {
image.src="bright.jpg";
}
}
```

When i run my code, it works partially , that is when i click, it will becomes bright, but again i click it didn't show as dim..

May i know what is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `image.src.match`: `image` - Image tag, `src` - src attribute, `match` - Check whether it matches with src attribute's value..

Comment: thank you so much for all your anwers.. I got it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if condition

```
if(image.src.match("bulbon"))
```

you are trying to match `bulbon` in your gif and both the gif does not have `bulbon` naming.

It should be like

```
if(image.src.match("bulbon"))
image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
}
else {
image.src="bulbon.jpg"; }
```

or check the bright image correctly like this:

```
if(image.src.match("bright")) {
image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
}
else {
image.src="bright.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Okay @Rahul Tripathi: so may i use bri or brigh instead of bright?

Comment: @saina:- You can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match to check how match works :)

Comment: that link quite complex.. but i am a newer, so can you able to tell me short? thanks

Comment: @saina:- The match method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches. So in your case when you try to search `bulbon` then it will search it in the string and if it matches then it return the match. So in your case it is "bulbon.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

> bulbon = bulb on

The code below simply checks if the image being used is the bulb with the light on and replaces the image with off version.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
} else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
}
```

To fix your code, change it to this:

```
function changebulb() {
    var image=document.getElementById("bulb");

    if(image.src.match("bright")) {
        image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
    }
    else {
        image.src="bright.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"bulbon" is part of the filename `pic_bulbon.gif`, but not `pic_bulboff.gif` so `if(image.src.match("bulbon")) {` is testing to see if the bulb is currently on.

The reason it onbly partially works is because you renamed the files - to get it working again, simply replace `bulbon` with `bright`:

```
<img width="300px" height="300px" src="dim-bulb.jpg" id="bulb" onclick="changebulb()"  alt=bulb"/>
<script>
function changebulb() {
   var image=document.getElementById("bulb");
   if(image.src.match("bright")) {
      image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
   }
   else {
      image.src="bright.jpg";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`bulbon` is the image name found in the `src` of the image tag when you see the bright light.

So when it is clicked you check the `src` and change the `src` to some other image let's say `bulboff`.

Your code should be like:

```
function changebulb() {
    // get the element with id 'bulb'
    var image=document.getElementById("bulb");
    // check the src attribute of the image tag
    if(image.src.match("dim-bulb")) {
        image.src="bright.jpg"; // change the src attribute
    } else {
        image.src="dim-bulb.jpg"; // change the src attribute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var image=document.getElementById("bulb");
if(image.src.match("dim-bulb")) {
image.src="bright.jpg";
}
else {
image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img width="300px" height="300px" src="dim-bulb.jpg" id="bulb"  onclick="changebulb()"  alt=bulb"/>
<script>
function changebulb() {

var image=document.getElementById("bulb");
if(image.src.match("dim-bulb.jpg")) {
 image.src="bright.jpg";
}
else {
 image.src="dim-bulb.jpg";
}
}
</script>
```

I think this may be answer to your question.